# How do I get the NetworkCategory prior to Windows 8 in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, network-programming

Occasionally, when we perform our maintenance cycle the domain controller will take too long and some of our virtual machines will default to the public network category instead of domain authenticated. After searching through BOL and Google, I found the [Get-NetConnectionProfile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj899566.aspx) cmdlet but it only seems to be available on Windows 2012 and later. We have some machines still running Windows 2008. I've already attempted to use the -CimSession switch to connect to a 2008 machine and it returned an error.

Is there a PowerShell equivalent for earlier versions of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The entire [CIM cmdlet](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/08/24/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets/) came out with Server 2012, and is representing this [CimClass class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.management.infrastructure.cimclass(v=vs.85).aspx) which is a part of [Windows Management Infrastructure(MI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152383(v=vs.85).aspx), also introduced in Server 2012. Which seems to be replacement of [Windows Management Instrumentation(WMI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx), or in Microsoft's word:

> The Windows Management Infrastructure (MI) features represent the
>   latest version of the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)

Thus is closest counter part you can get is [Get-WMIObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315379.aspx) cmdlet in eailer OS. The item you looking for, should be `MSFT_NetConnectionProfile`. Unfortunately I didn't find anything similar from `get-wmiobject -list`. I also checked documentation here [Networking Device Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273(v=vs.85).aspx#_hmm_networking_device_classes) without luck.

If you give get-wmiobject a shot, I don't expect it would return things exactly the same, but maybe some wmi object(s) would return the item you care most?

Comment: I tried get-wmiobject with several different objects but none of them appear to include the information I'm looking for (still looking). MSFT_NetConnectionProfile is new with Server 2012 along with CIM and so can't be used either.